# How can I find coordinates of points along a curved path?

Tags: curves, bezier-curve

I have a very basic grasp of the math concepts behind this question so I need a very basic explanation if at all possible.  The question is in regards to a game program where a player is traveling through a curved course made up of bezier curves. The curves are all $90$ degrees in terms of the start and end points.  I have the start coordinates of each section and the end coordinates of each section.  In the image example I have a curve section which starts at $x= 0$, $y= 0$ (the red square) and ends at $x = +100$, $y = +100$ (the green square).  I need to determine the coordinates of some points along the curve (the black squares).

Rather than just the "equation" to determine the points (I don't really understand a lot of the symbols used in equations or how to translate that to programming code), I need to know the sequence of basic math steps to get the $x$-$y$ coordinates of the points.  If possible some "pseudo code" would be great to help me understand how to achieve coordinates for several points along the curve.

[example image to understand my question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7yRX.png)

Comment: Unless you can give the equation of the curve, I don't see how anyone can answer this.

Comment: I think you’ll have to use some sort of equation or inequality. No reason to shy away from doing so though. And programming with equations can be powerful

Comment: I don't understand what that means unfortunately.  The game uses a 3d model (made in blender) of a simple bezier curve (made into a tube).  The model is rotated to different orientations to make the course.  Starting at 0,0 in the world space and using a "right hand turn" version of the model, the tube ends at exactly +100 units in the X direction (left to right in world space) and +100 units in the Z direction (depth, or front to back in world space).   I am not concerned with the 3d aspect, just need the point coordinates in 2D space, hence my example uses X and Y.

Comment: Curves are typically vector functions with respect to a single real variable, possibly with a restricted domain. So something like $c(t)=(x(t),y(t))$ for a curve in the plane with the $x$ and $y$ coordinates provided by $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ respectively. You have to know what the curve is to calculate the points on the curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the curve is an quarter of circle, and that the six point are spaced uniformly, we can write
$$
(x,y)=(100+100\cos t,100\sin t), \quad t=\frac{\pi}{2}+k\frac{\pi}{10}, \quad k=0,\ldots,5
$$
so we have
\begin{align}
&(100., 100.),\\ 
&(69.0983, 95.1057),\\ 
&(41.2215, 80.9017),\\ 
&(19.0983, 58.7785),\\
&(4.89435, 30.9017),\\
&(0., 0.)
\end{align}

Here a short piece of program in C++ (not tested)

```
double pi = 3.14159;
for (int k = 0; k <= 5; k++) {
  double t = pi/2 + k*pi/10;
  double x = 100+100*cos(t);
  double y = 100*sin(t);
  printf("%f, %f\n", x, y);
}
```

Comment: Ok this is a great start, yes the curve is a quarter of a circle.  What I don't understand in your answer -  what is t and what is k? and what is represented by the three dots between 0 and 5.  Can you give me this answer in terms of steps I can program in C++?

Comment: @JonEnstrom think of $t$ as time and the curve is sketched out over time by a pen which is at position $x(t), y(t)$ at time $t$.

Comment: Okay sure but like I mentioned in the original post, I am not strong in math so I don't understand how this equation helps me with the program.  I can't simply type that equation into my C++ program and get the coordinates so I need more break down into the steps themselves that I can actually write code to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you for the code snippet!  I think this could be exactly what I need, I will test it right away!

Comment: @JonEnstrom I edited the answer adding a piece of code

Comment: Amazing job providing the answer, it works perfectly thank you!  I adjusted the code to work in 3D space by determining which dimension is unchanged since each "tube section" only travels in two dimensions, and then using your code snippet to act upon either X/Z or X/Y or Y/Z coordinates accordingly.  Again thank you very much!